# How can I debug the packaged multiplatform-compose-desktop app , like macOS?

Tags: debugging, package, kotlin-multiplatform, compose-multiplatform

I wrote an application by multiplatform compose for desktop platform and I wish it could run on Mac, linux and Windows well.

It does run well from Intellij IDEA `run`, and obviously I can check the log in Intellij Idea. But when I package the app into dmg and install it on my Mac, it goes wrong, like `index should be non-negative` shows up. I don't know what happend since I don't know how to debug the package application.

Is there any log files were printed and stored in somewhere?
Or is there any tools can debug the packaged application like adb-tools in Android?

Answer (score 1):

1. `Logback` can satisfy my requirement. Setting your `src/commonMain/resources/logback.xml` and it can print logs to both consoles and files.
   like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <contextListener class="LoggerStartupListener"/>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${logFilePath}</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="io.netty" level="INFO"/>

    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="io.netty" level="INFO"/>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</configuration>
```

`LoggerStartupListener` runs at app start and gives `logback.xml` a file path value

```kotlin
open class LoggerStartupListener : ContextAwareBase(), LoggerContextListener, LifeCycle {

    private var started = false

    override fun start() {
        val databasePath =
            File(System.getProperty("compose.application.resources.dir"), "passwd_log.log")
        val logFile = File(System.getProperty("compose.application.resources.dir"), "passwd_log.log")
        val context = getContext()
        context.putProperty("logFilePath", logFile.absolutePath)
        println("[LoggerStartupListener] (start) logFilePath: " + logFile.absolutePath)
        started = true
    }

    override fun isStarted(): Boolean {
        return started
    }
}
```

2. If you just want to know what is happening while running apps that opened from `~/Applications/xxx`, you can `right click the app` --> `open package` --> `Contents` --> `MacOS` and click `xxx`, the app will run with a console where logs would be printed

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way to debug release package:
just run the task `./gradlew runReleaseDistributable`. All related debug info, like console println and log4j logs will be printed.